# what is the use of /wp-includes/SimplePie?

Tags: php, database

I have this location on my server. `/home/localhost/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie.` I have not installed Simplepie plugin. What is it used for since it is not associated with Simplepie plugin.
The reason I ask is that, I have fatal error generated from different php files in that location. Each time I debug the error a new error in different file which is at the same location is created. Later I found that it was associated with a plugin. I have removed the plugin but the folder still exist.
What is that used for.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's used by wordpress core for parsing RSS & Atom feeds. You probably know that wordpress puts all plugins and themes into the wp-content folder so that you don't need to worry about any other folders/files. Leave it be.

Comment: so if i delete it, it will effect the database.?

Comment: It will affect the functionality offered by Wordpress. If you have errors, make sure your Wordpress is up to date. Are they really errors or just info/notices?

Comment: fatal errors are shown

Comment: Ok, that helped anyway, I wonder why questions here are getting many negative ratings.! This question was a public interest question. And still this negative rating.  May be because of I am a newbie. So lame.

Comment: @owleye - Downvotes are defined as relating to questions that do not show any research effort, are unclear or not useful(it's in the tooltip when you hover over downvote).